# Check for duplicate letters in a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding and I've found myself quite lost on a question.
I'm confused about the following Codewars challenge:

> An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or
> non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string
> that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is
> an isogram. Ignore letter case.

```
   Example: (Input --> Output)
    
"Dermatoglyphics" --> true
"aba" --> false
"moOse" --> false (ignore letter case)
```

I had to look up solutions and found one! But I couldn't understand each line of code:

```
function isIsogram(str){
   var i, j;
   str = str.toLowerCase();
   for(i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
     for(j = i + 1; j < str.length; ++j) {
       if(str[i] === str[j]) {
         return false;
       }
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```

My questions are:

- why did this solution include " var i, j; " instead of let " let i = '' "
- why did this person loop through this twice?
- in the second for loop, why is there a +1 in  "j = i + 1"

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding the line `console.log(\`str[${i}] === str[${j}] => ${str[i]} === ${str[j]}\`);`  right before the `if` to get a better idea of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your question is as follows,

1. using 'var' here instead of 'let' has no impact in this code( considering its the only piece of code where variables i and j are used)
2. its the logic, you know the question, you have to compare 2 letters to know whether they are same or not.
3. in the first loop, you are taking the first letter `str[i]` and comparing with other letters `str[j]`.

For instance, take `i=0`, then `str[0]` , it is the first letter in the given word, you are comparing it with str[1], if both are same letters, then the word is not an isogram, otherwise compare `str[0]` with `str[2]`, and so on. This is the purpose of second loop.

Once `str[0]` is compared with all the other letters, its time to compare `str[1]` with other letters.(second iteration of the `i` loop)

I hope this clarifies your doubt. And by the way, your code has some flaw, I am leaving it to you to fix it by yourself. Its very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you found should work correctly, but it doesn't ignore the letter case, in fact it turns all the letter to lower case `str = str.toLowerCase()`.

I don't know why it uses `var` instead of `let`, I can't find a reason why it should declare a function scope variable in this case.

Answering the second and the third question:

- it loops twice in the string to check one letter (`str[i]`) with all the other letters (`str[j]`);
- there's `j = i + 1` because if `j` was the same as `i` the code would control the same letter in the string, resulting a repeating letter.

Hope I answered your question.